# CSharpCodeProvider "string" contains no definition for "Select". CSCC having problems with System.Linq

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, csharpcodeprovider

I'm trying to use **CSharpCodeProvider** to **compile a piece of code**.

**The error is:**

```
c:\...\crust.cs(551,48) : error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The **code being compiled** is:

```
using System;
...
using System.Linq;

...

          return new string(str.Substring(1).Select(character => (char)((character - 54545) ^ key)).ToArray());
...
```

The **code compiling the source** is as follows:

```
...
                String exeName = String.Format("NAME.exe");

                CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters
                {
                    GenerateExecutable = true,
                    GenerateInMemory = false,
                    OutputAssembly = "NAME.exe",
                    CompilerOptions = "/target:exe /platform:x64"
                };

                cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
                ...
                cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Linq.dll");
                cp.GenerateExecutable = true;
                cp.OutputAssembly = exeName;
                cp.GenerateInMemory = false;
                cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
                CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp,
                    sourceName);
...
```

No other system.linq methods work either.

Notes:
Compiler is 64 bit
Source is being compiled in to 64 bit
Compiler is in .net framework 4.0
Source is being compiled in to .net 4.0

Comment: Have you checked what is the Linq dependency version for CSharpCodeProvider ? Maybe it is a version that does not accept the Select method with string as first param

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you haven't declared using statment for 'System.Linq' package:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Check it out in the cs file and make sure the using statment is declared explicitly.

Comment: He shows using System.Linq in the original post.